# Snowflake returning 0 to N records when I expect exactly 1 record

Tags: sql, random, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, uniform-distribution

Something that I'm not expecting is going on here. I have a table `applications` with 22 records with IDs 1 to 22.

I'd like to randomly select 1 record for sample data. But rather than selecting each row with equal probability, I'd like a more interesting (realistic??) distribution. I settled on the product of 2 uniform random variables. The choice of `25` below was to keep the tail from being too tiny, but I think that's not important to the issue.

My query isn't overly complicated. I added the CTE as a convenience so that anyone can run this as a self-contained query. But in my actual query I get this behavior with no CTE.

```
with applications as (
    select 1 + seq4() as ID, randstr(5, random()) as NAME
    from table(generator(rowcount => 22)) v
)
SELECT
    NAME
    , ID
FROM
    applications a
WHERE
    a.ID = LEAST(
        (
            SELECT 1 + round( 25 * uniform(0::float, 1::float, random()) * uniform(0::float, 1::float, random()) )
        )
        , 22
    )
```

It returns rows with a frequency that seems great for my purposes... but there's a catch. I do not understand why this query **returns a variable number of records**.

Returning 1 record appears to be the most common result. But returning 0 or 2 records happens regularly. Sometimes 3. I haven't seen 4 records... but maybe it's possible.

In the example below you can see that I got 2 records. How is it possible that `ID` is equal to both 4 and 7?

[image]

I'm quite interested in both:

- Why do I get 0 to N records with this query?
- What variation would produce exactly 1 record in all cases?

Comment: not sure exactly, but it looks to me that in the WHERE part it calls a random value for every row => sometimes you can even have 0 rows. If I am correct then you can assign a random value to a variable first and then use the variable in WHERE. E.g. you can write an SP that 1. assign a new random value for your var, 2. do the select

Comment: Yes, you must be on the right path. @NickW's answer builds on this idea as well. In practice one might say, "Don't put the random part in the `where` clause." But I'm still not 100% clear on why that's the case.

Comment: if I am right then running your query infinite number of times once will produce 22 rows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that I don't know why this is happening - but if you look at the query profile you may be able to see what's going on.

However, a solution seems to be to put the calculation of the filter value in a CTE rather than in the main SQL statement. The following only gives me one record each time I've run it:

```
with filter_value (fil_val) as (
    SELECT 1 + 
    round( 25 * uniform(0::float, 1::float, random()) * 
    uniform(0::float, 1::float, random()) )
)
SELECT
    NAME
    , ID
FROM
    applications a
WHERE A.ID = LEAST((SELECT FIL_VAL FROM FILTER_VALUE), 22)
;
```

Comment: The mathematician in me is unhappy and wants a clearer explanation. But the engineer in me recognizes that this completely meets my requirements, so I'm moving on. Thanks for the simple workaround!

Comment: The `explain` results clarified nothing for me... but it's a reasonable idea. Perhaps someone else will see the key point of confusion that way.